# How do I easily negate an expression in MS Report?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I'm converting af Crystal report to a MS report.
My expression in the Crystal report was like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing and Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing,
0,
IIF(Fields!foo.Value Is Not Nothing and Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing,
Fields!foo.Value,
IIF(Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing and Fields!bar.Value Is Not Nothing,
Fields!bar.Value * -1,
IIF(Fields!foo.Value Is Not Nothing and Fields!bar.Value Is Not Nothing,
Fields!foo.Value,
0
))))
```

The `Not` does not work here, even thought the text is blue.

Can I use `Not` or something like `!`or do I have to go crazy with `IsNothing()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your expression to:

```
IIF(Not Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing, 
    Fields!foo.Value,
    IIF(Not Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing,
        Fields!bar.Value * -1,
        0))
```

EDIT: To return foo.Value - bar.Value when neither is null, try:

```
= IIF(Not Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing, Fields!foo.Value, 0) -
  IIF(Not Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing, Fields!bar.Value, 0)
```

Comment: Your are right I can reduce it. But I made a mistake when i wrote the question. If both foo and bar is not null, the value I want to return is (foo.Value - bar.Value). So I can't trim my code more but your answer is better than mine. :)

Comment: @radbyx: See my edited answer for a simplified formula to return foo.Value - bar.Value when neither is null.

Answer (score 2):

Oh I figured it out, I just had to move the `Not`to the start of the expression. 
It was a VB.NET syntax error from me. Coming from C#, VB.NET and MS Reports are new to me, I am sorry.

```
=IIF(Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing and Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing,
0,
IIF(Not Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing and Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing,
Fields!foo.Value,
IIF(Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing and Not Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing,
Fields!bar.Value * -1,
IIF(Not Fields!foo.Value Is Nothing and Not Fields!bar.Value Is Nothing,
Fields!foo.Value,
0
))))
```

Comment: You can also use the form `If xyz IsNot Nothing`

Comment: Thanks alot Meta-Knight. Another one of those things you only need to learn one time and can use forever :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IIF((Fields!foo.Value.Equals(System.DBNull.Value)), "YES", "NO")
=IIF((Fields!foo.Value is System.DBNull.Value), "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: Then I could just use the IsNothing method. I just need something like the "!" in C#

Comment: =IIF( not(Fields!foo.Value is System.DBNull.Value), "YES", "NO") ? huh :)